# How can i check if the UI is refreshing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I have a problem when I use a widget for showing a list of items by a future builder, I have a filter object and when I change something in filter screen, automatically get the change in list screen, but always show me the same data but the items list have a different items that the UI is showing.

This is my container:

```dart
body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FutureBuilder<ResponseHome>(
          future: Connection(context: context).filterPlaces(filter: _filter),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return _formatCategories(context, snapshot.data.news, snapshot.data.places);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              var message = Utils.parseError(context, snapshot.error);
              return Center(
                child: Text("$message"),
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
```

This is the function that i use for make the widget:

```
Widget _formatCategories(BuildContext context, List<Publication> publications, ResponsePlaces response) {
    List<Category> categories = <Category>[];

    if (response.hotels.isNotEmpty) {
      categories.add(Category(title: "Hoteles", places: response.hotels));
    }

    if (response.restaurants.isNotEmpty) {
      categories.add(Category(title: "Restaurantes", places: response.restaurants));
    }

    if (response.touristic.isNotEmpty) {
      categories.add(Category(title: "Actividades", places: response.touristic));
    }

    for (var category in categories) {
      print("Category ${category.title}  ${category.places.length}");
    }

    return _containerLists(context, publications, categories);
  }


  Widget _containerLists(BuildContext context, List<Publication> publications, List<Category> categories) {

    List<Widget> items = <Widget>[];

    items.clear();

    items.add(
        Routes.newsSlider(publications)
    );

    for (var index in categories) {
      items.add(
          Routes.placeList(index)
      );
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: items,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the evidence if you see I pick another type of place, but always showing me the hotels.

And this is the evidence that I got a list with different data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIwoN.png

Comment: You forgot to add one of the urls

Comment: @PhaniRithvij which one url?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen in case you have the same size of your `items` List. If that's true, then your Element Tree couldn't recognize that Widgets in your Column has changed and you have to use UniqueKey for them. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d), try to apply it and give a feedback please